# Please help me in finding the solutions of the Bernoulli D.E.:- y'+(y/3)=(1/3)*(1-2x)*(y^4)

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Please Help,
When I am solving the bernoulli differential equation, I am getting only **one** answer:-  y(x)=[1/((ce^x)-2x-1)]^(1/3), where c is a constant.

But, in the wolfram alpha there are 3 answers for this differential equation which are as follows:-

1. y(x)=[1/((ce^x)-2x-1)]^(1/3)
2. y(x)=-((-1)/((ce^x)-2x-1)]^(1/3)
3. y(x)=[(-1)^2/((ce^x)-2x-1)]^(1/3)

Although all 3 have equal values, but **How 3 different solutions are coming**?

Comment: The solutions look identical **if all the values are real**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'+\frac{y}{3}=\frac{(1-2x)y^4}{3}\implies y^{-4}y'+\frac{y^{-3}}{3}=\frac{(1-2x)}{3}. $$ Let $y^{-3}=v \implies -3y^{-4}y'=v'$, to get a linear ODE
$$v'-v=(2x-1)$$
Its integrating factor is $I=e^{-x}$, then
$$v=e^{x} \int e^{-x} (2x-1) dx+C e^x
 \implies v=-(1+2x)+C e^{x}.$$
Finally, $$y^{-3}=-(1+2x)+Ce^x$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Z Ahmed for your answer. Self has also reach till the final step. But, from here I have confusion whether y(x) has 3 identical (equal) solution or the 3 different solutions that I have provided in the question description. If possible, Please provide an explanation/solution.